# How to get the projectId in pom.xml from GCLOUD_CONFIG for the endpoints-framework-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, gcloud

For the Google endpoints documentation I need to provide a `<hostname>${endpoints.project.id}.appspot.com</hostname>` but I want that to come from the GCLOUD_CONFIG. How is this possible?

Plugin Configuration

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>endpoints-framework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <hostname>${endpoints.project.id}.appspot.com</hostname>
                    <serviceClasses>
                        com.example.pratyum.guice.AllEndpoint
                    </serviceClasses>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>discoveryDocs</goal>
                            <goal>openApiDocs</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to use the GCLOUD_CONFIG setting for making the SDK fill in the service hostname.

It is not possible also to use it as the means to provide a suffix/prefix with the project ID.

The most common use cases (replacing `projectId` and `version`) have very specific behaviours. The first replaces the string with the project ID and the second generates a unique version ID.